# How to check if a program is installed on Windows system

Tags: java, windows

How can I check with Java if a program is installed on a Windows system, for example to check for Mozilla Firefox?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about Windows. As Java is intented to be a platform independent language and the way how to determine it differs per platform, there's no standard Java API to check that. You can however do it with help of [JNI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html) calls on a DLL which crawls the Windows registry. You can then just check if the registry key associated with the software is present in the registry. There's a 3rd party Java API with which you can crawl the Windows registry: [jRegistryKey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jregistrykey/).

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with help of jRegistryKey:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2439984;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;

import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey;
import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RootKey;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        RegistryKey.initialize(Test.class.getResource("jRegistryKey.dll").getFile());
        RegistryKey key = new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKLM, "Software\\Mozilla");
        for (Iterator<RegistryKey> subkeys = key.subkeys(); subkeys.hasNext();) {
            RegistryKey subkey = subkeys.next();
            System.out.println(subkey.getName()); // You need to check here if there's anything which matches "Mozilla FireFox".
        }
    }

}
```

If you however intend to have a platformindependent application, then you'll also have to take into account the Linux/UNIX/Mac/Solaris/etc (in other words: anywhere where Java is able to run) ways to detect whether FF is installed. Else you'll have to distribute it as a Windows-only application and do a `System#exit()` along with a warning whenever `System.getProperty("os.name")` does not Windows.

Sorry, I don't know how to detect in other platforms whether FF is installed or not, so don't expect an answer from me for that ;)

Comment: the registry is not always cleared when an application is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API I know of that will allow you to do this - I expect the most general method is to check file locations.

Other approaches (like checking Windows registry) are OS-dependent.