# How to check from python, if an arbitrary program is installed

Tags: python, windows, service, checkinstall

I guess what I'm looking for is closer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439984/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-installed-on-system).

I'm running a python script (on a windows machine) that requires a program and a service to be installed. Since I have no control over which machines my script will be run on, I need to check from within my script, whether or not the program and service are installed on the machine.

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: I'm not looking to check if a python module is installed. I know that I can do that very easily by just trying to import it. I'm trying to check if a program (say Mozilla Firefox) is installed on the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer edited since you clarified your question.

you can use the [winreg](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html) module to do a check similar to your Java post.

More specifically, you can use the OpenKey method in a try block, catching a WindowsError if the key isn't found.

Comment: I know this. Please check the edit. I'm looking to check for a program like say, Mozilla Firefox

Comment: oh - there's a winreg module that provides access to the windows registry. Similar in nature to the Java link you posted.

Comment: This is perfect. I was looking for `_winreg`. I was unable to figure out the python equivalent from that question