# How to check if a program is installed on system using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, registry

Is there a way to access the windows registry system using coldfusion. Something like this [How to check if a program is installed on Windows system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439984/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-installed-on-system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for cfregistry

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c6f.html

Comment: I will try this but seems perfect