# Java, check if an executable exists in PATH environment

Tags: java, environment-variables

I can print the path using `System.getenv("PATH")`. 
Then I probably can traverse those paths and use `File` to check if the file is exist.

Is there any faster way in Java ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think there's a better way than what you propose

Comment: @Nix is that question in SCALA ? I'm asking in JAVA dude

Comment: @w00d did you see any similarities between the answer below, and the answer for that question ?  This link is also on the same subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439984/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-installed-on-system .  Take some time and research yourself `dude.`

Comment: JAVA has a huge library, and I wonder if some libraries have the support for this. Your 2nd link has answer for specific Windows Mozilla, not work for me.

Comment: @Nix I don't know what are you arguing about? I have given my reasoning that it's not a duplication. I had also given my solution, here I am asking for a better way.

Comment: The answer in the link proposed by @Nix is useful for Java too.

Comment: This is not necessarily a duplicate. There are some alternative answers below that are actually better than the one that this thread is supposedly a duplicate of. Once again the SO post censors are at it...

Comment: you can use the where command under windows. cmd /c where appExec. Then on the returned trimmed string you can do:  if(shellResult!=null && shellResult.endsWith('git-bash.exe')) ..... bla bla

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");` in `try ... catch` section. If app won't be in `PATH` you will get an exception.

**[EDIT]**

But .. this will execute app instead of check. Sorry.

Comment: won't this have the side affect of actually executing the command?

Comment: you can use the where command under windows. cmd /c where appExec. Then on the returned trimmed string you can do: if(shellResult!=null && shellResult.endsWith('git-bash.exe')) ..... bla bla

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any faster way in Java ?

In terms of performance, no.

In terms of coding effort, probably no.  Certainly I'm not aware of any 3rd-party Java library that will search the command search path to see if an executable exists.

Unfortunately searching for an executable on Windows is a little tricky because you have to account for the various types of executable ... based on file suffixes.  Even on Linux / Unix you need to use the new Java 7 file attributes APIs to determine if a candidate file has the execute permissions set.

(I am aware that some commands can be run in ways that are harmless; e.g. they may support an option / argument that outputs a version string, or some help info.  However, that only works in specific cases.  I'm also aware that on Unix / Linux, there is a built-in shell command called "whereis" that can tell you if an executable command with a given name exists on the search path.)

Comment: you can use the where command under windows. cmd /c where appExec. Then on the returned trimmed string you can do: if(shellResult!=null && shellResult.endsWith('git-bash.exe')) ..... bla bla

Answer (score 3):

Your approach will work.

I suggest using the [File.listFiles(FileFilter filter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) method on each directory in the path. This will make searching each directory simpler.