# How to support both older and newer version of Firefox simultaneously using selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I have multiple version of `Firefox` in multiple **PCs** where some has **newest** which is `47` and some has **older version**.

I have following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)
and setup `RemoteWebDriver` with `Marionette`, the next generation of `FirefoxDriver` to support **Firefox version 47** for automation as below :-

```
URL server = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(server, capabilities);
webDriver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

It's working fine with **Firefox version 47** but when I'm running same on other **PCs** where installed **Firefox older version**, it's giving `exception` as below :-

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:
>   Could not sta
>
> rt a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or br
>
> owser start-up failure.
>
> Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15
>   17:00:58'
>
> System info: host: 'com-PC', ip: '192.168.3.3', os.name: 'Windows 7',
>   os.arch: '
>
> x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: MarionetteDriver
>
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHost
>
> ConnectException: Connect to localhost:3125 [localhost/127.0.0.1]
>   failed: Connec
>
> tion refused: connect
>
> Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15
>   17:00:58'
>
> System info: host: 'com-PC', ip: '192.168.3.3', os.name: 'Windows 7',
>   os.arch: '
>
> x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: MarionetteDriver
>
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>
> WARN - Exception: Connection refused: connect

When I removes line `capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);` means removes `MarionetteDriver` support, it's working well with **Firefox older version** but raising `exception` with **Firefox version 47** ie. `UnreachableBrowserExcetion`.

So my question is :-

Is there any way to know `Firefox version` or any othere solution by which I could run simultaneously with both **Old** and **New** version of **Firefox**??.

I want a **generic solution** where my code intelligently could be able to know when it will start with `MarionetteDriver` and when with `FireFoxDriver` on the basis of `FireFox Version`.

Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now I have achieved this by following approach :-

```
public static String executeCommand(List<String> commands)
            throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        return r.readLine();
    }

//this command gives the current installed path of Firefox in c drive 
String[] getInstalledFirefoxDirectoryCmd = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "dir /s/b \"C:/firefox.exe\""};

String installedFirefoxLocation = executeCommand(Arrays.asList(getInstalledFirefoxDirectoryCmd));

//this command will give version of the installed Firefox
String[] getFirefoxVersionCmd = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "\"" + installedFirefoxLocation + "\" -v | more" };

String version = executeCommand(Arrays.asList(getFirefoxVersionCmd));

int version_int = Integer.parseInt(version.replace("Mozilla Firefox ", "").split("\\.")[0]);

URL server = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

//use marionette if ff version equal or greater than 47
if(version_int >= 47) {
     capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
}

WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(server, capabilities);
webDriver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

By this generic way we can automate our test in multiple **PCs** with same code. No matter which version of **Firefox** installed on those **Pcs**.

**Edited..**

For **Mac Pcs**  we can change the `command` to get version of installed `Firefox` as below :-

```
String installedFirefoxLocation = "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox"
// it's default location

String[] getFirefoxVersionCmd = { installedFirefoxLocation + " -v | more" };
```

If `firefox` is not installed in default location then we can provide `Firefox` binary location either by path or by `System` property because selenium does not work without providing `Firefox` binary `location` if it is installed in other location.

For checking `OS` we can use as below :-

```
String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

if(OS.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
//Means it's windows
}

if(OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0) {
//Means it's mac
}
```

...:)

Comment: This seems unnecessary long and complex compared to the answer Mobrockers provided you earlier. The answer which you called too long.

Comment: This also does not work on any different OS, nor does it work on machines that have firefox installed in a different location.

Comment: @RemcoW here I'm not comparing which answer is better..for diffrent OS just need to change command line which I have provided in my edited answer...Have you tried ever to launch ff from different location using selenium??....90% `Pcs` has default location...and FYI if location is not default selenium ask for binary location of firefox...so this case does not need to execute my first command which gives the ff binaty location...

Comment: I might be a student, however I know what I'm talking about. All I'm doing is providing feedback on this answer so other users know what is wrong with this method as you failed to mention this in your answer. This way when they encounter the same issue they will know the pro's and cons of the answer and can make a decision on an implementation accordingly. There is no need to make rude comments and try to make smart remarks. All I'm doing is increasing the quality of your answer to help out others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Set a boolean flag at the beginning of your test depending on if you want to run it on 43 or 47. Check the flag in the code where you're creating your driver, for example like this:

```
boolean useMarionette = true //false

URL server = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", useMarionette);
WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(server, capabilities);
webDriver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

Now if you have useMarionette set to true, it will run with marionette, if set to false, it will not.

If you really want to parse the windows registry for the available firefox version, here is a partial example for you:

[How to check if a program is installed on Windows system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439984/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-installed-on-windows-system)

Use as follows:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        RegistryKey firefoxKey;
        RegistryKey.initialize(Test.class.getResource("jRegistryKey.dll").getFile());
        RegistryKey key = new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKCU, "SOFTWARE\\Mozilla\\Mozilla Firefox");
        for (Iterator<RegistryKey> subkeys = key.subkeys(); subkeys.hasNext();) {
            firefoxKey = subkeys.next();

            if(firefoxKey.getName().contains("47") {
                 //marionette
            }
            //start browser with or without     marionette
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I couldn't do this on the basis of flag.. I want more generic solution where my code intelligently could be able to know  when it will run with `MarionetteDriver` and when with `FireFoxDriver`..

Comment: The only way I see to do this in a generic way is to try and request a webbrowser and catch the exception, and on exception request the other. Which is extremely bad design. You should be in control of where you tests are running, it is your environment after all, so you should decide how the tests are going to run.

Comment: Are you running the tests in a distributed selenium grid or starting them manually?

Comment: I want to run same code with multiple machine where I don't know which version of firefox running in all machine

Comment: What you're asking is not possible then. You can only ask the grid to give you the browser you're looking for, you cannot ask it which browsers it has.

Comment: Why is it not possible???.. the code will be run on the local machine but I could not modify the code on the basis on machine... but I can know which  version of firefox is installed on that local machine because I'm using java..

Comment: I have added a partial solution to find out the installed firefox version number... But I would really really not recommend doing this.